# how to import Zxing IntentIntegrator in android

Tags: android

how do i import Zxing  IntentIntegrator class to use it in my project , is it a library project ?

[Zxing IntentIntegrator](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android-integration/src/com/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentIntegrator.java)

Comment: it still asks me to install Barcode Scanner App from playstore.How did you resolve this.

Comment: i download Zxing code and use in it my project , i dont call it by intent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to compile its project to a JAR using `ant`, then add that JAR to the `libs/` directory of your Android project. [Here is a sample app demonstrating the use of `IntentIntegrator`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/ZXing), and you are welcome to copy the JAR out of the `libs/` directory of that project if you wish (though it may not be the latest and greatest version of the code from ZXing).

Comment: i import lib file from there but its asking me to install some App and when i click yes it intall barcode reader app , i want to embbed scanner in my project so that it cannot ask for installation and work independiently

Comment: @sara: Then you do not want `IntentIntegrator`. What you want is not recommended and not supported by the ZXing team, and I do not have any instructions handy for how to do it.

Comment: If what you want is to use the barcode scanner or just Zxing, you dont need Intent Integrator to do it so.